# sscanf input buffer from file failing from within file read scope but works just beyond file read scope Why?

Tags: c++, c++11, scanf

So I don't understand why this is happening but the first method of this code fails and the buffer is not initialized I guess within the file read scope so `sscanf` has bad data to parse and fails. Once `sscanf` is outside of the file read scope the buffer is filled and `sscanf` works fine. I also used to file input data to feed a parse function that used `sscanf` and it also works, can anyone point out what I am missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <window.h>

void readFromFile() {
    char buff[100];
    int op = 0;
    int lc = 0;
    char st[25];
    FILE *cmdBUffer;
    std::string CMDFILE = "C:\\testFile.txt";
    // example test file string 50 0005 SomeString

    //-----  This works and op and lc are in fact integers 
    cmdBuffer = fopen(CMDFILE.data(), "r");
    if (cmdBuffer != NULL) {
        fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), cmdBuffer);
        fclose(cmdBuffer);
    }
    sscanf(buff, "%d %d %s", &op, &lc, st);
    printf(" %d %d %s\n", op, lc, st);
}
```

```
    //-----  this always fails ----
    cmdBuffer = fopen(CMDFILE.data(), "r");
    if (cmdBuffer != NULL) {
        fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), cmdBuffer);
        sscanf(buff, "%d %d %s", &op, &lc, st);
        fclose(cmdBuffer);
    }
    printf("%d %d %s", op, lc, st); // op and lc are always zero after sscanf fail
```

Comment: Your last `printf` has a typo causing UB. There are three format specifiers, but only two arguments. Also the first format argument has the wrong type. I am voting to close the question as a simple typo.

Comment: Please specify the exact input, desired output and actual output.

Comment: `//-----  this always fails ----` Do you run this outside main()? What errors do you get?

Comment: Why this is tagged `C++`? This is pure `C` code.

Comment: @MarekR: The posted code does use `std::string`, which only exists in C++. Therefore, the `c++` tag is correct.

Comment: @MarekR yes it is mostly C but I always use C++ for compiler so I can use classes namespaces etc.

Comment: @kiner_shah it was called from a running class object but above was mrc I should have just put it as int main() function but was trying to should how I was using it. and no errors sscanf just fails and returns 0 for 0 interpreted/ conversions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues:

- you must handle errors more explicitly and accurately: if you cannot open the file, `buff` stays uninitialized  so passing to `sscanf()` is meaningless and has undefined behavior.  You should report the error and use default values for `op`, `lc` and `st`.
- You don't check the return value of `sscanf()` so there is way to tell if `sscanf` *fails* and why.  If `sscanf()` returns anything different from 3, some or all of the destination variables are unmodified, and `st` stays uninitialized, causing undefined behavior in the `printf` call.
- you use `%s` in `sscanf`: this is risky as `buff` may contain a word longer than `24` bytes. Use `sscanf(buff, "%d %d %24s", &op, &lc, st)` to avoid a buffer overflow.
- in `printf("%d %d %s, &op\n", &lc, st)` you pass the address of `lc` instead of its value, and `st` instead of another integer, producing huge numbers (actually undefined behavior), and you print `&op` instead of passing `op` value... You should use `printf("%d %d %s\n", op, lc, st)`

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int readFromFile() {
    char buff[100];
    int op;
    int lc;
    char st[25];
    // example test file string 50 0005 SomeString
    const char *CMDFILE = "C:\\testFile.txt";
    FILE *cmdBUffer = fopen(CMDFILE, "r");
    if (cmdBuffer == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open file %s: %s\n", CMDFILE, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    if (!fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), cmdBuffer)) {
        printf("file %s is empty\n", CMDFILE);
        fclose(cmdBuffer);
        return -2;
    }
    if (sscanf(buff, "%d %d %24s", &op, &lc, st) != 3) {
        printf("invalid file contents: %s\n", buff);
        fclose(cmdBuffer);
        return -3;
    }
    fclose(cmdBuffer);
    printf(" %d %d %s\n", op, lc, st);
    // ... do further processing
    return 0;  // no error
}
```